# Mac Authentication php?

Tags: php

```
$pid = mysql_insert_id();
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
    exit();
}
```

I am using the above code to add images to a folder from a form on my webpage.
I keep getting the following error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../inventory_images/11.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/storeadmin/inventory_list.php on line 63

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpH51nOR' to '../inventory_images/11.jpg' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/storeadmin/inventory_list.php on line 63
```

Is this due to folder authentication?

Comment: Your error DOES state **`Permission denied`**.  What are the permissions on the target folder?

Comment: Well each time I save to this area it requests my password for authentication. I don't understand this though as I am the only user and admin on the machine?

Comment: We don't know what operating system you're using, let alone the authentication scheme it uses.  Also, what does this have to do with SQL or e-commerce?

Comment: Apologies for the tags, they stayed in the form from my last post.

Comment: Destination folder needs to be writable via file permissions; is it currently set to be able to be written to?